# How can I align tab border with items length?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, json

The length of the data coming from json is not equal to the angle of the cart.
It is necessary to align the length of the main tab with the length of the items

[image: I have to make one like in the photo]

How can I align tab border with items length?

I will leave a screenshot and source code to make it more understandable

```
import React from "react";

import Data from "../../assets/data/data.json";

const Cards = () => {
  const cards = Data;
  const cardItems = cards.map((card) => {
    return (
      <div key={card.id} className="card1">
        <div className="card-header">{card.cat_name}</div>

        <div key={card.item.id}>
          {card.item.map((item) => (
            <div className="card-item" key={item.id}>
              {/* Header Title */}
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  marginBottom: "8px",
                }}
              >
                <div className="card-div">
                  <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                  <p>{item.title}</p>
                </div>
                <span
                  style={{
                    transform: "rotate(90deg)",
                    fontSize: "14px",
                    fontweight: 400,
                    lineHeight: "14px",
                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                  }}
                >
                  &hellip;
                </span>
              </div>

              {/* body */}
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  marginTop: "20px",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <span className="status">{item.status}</span>
                <span className="candidates">
                  <svg
                    style={{ marginRight: "6px" }}
                    width="16"
                    height="16"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                    fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M6.00001 7.33333C7.47277 7.33333 8.66668 6.13943 8.66668 4.66667C8.66668 3.19391 7.47277 2 6.00001 2C4.52725 2 3.33334 3.19391 3.33334 4.66667C3.33334 6.13943 4.52725 7.33333 6.00001 7.33333Z"
                      stroke="#96A09B"
                      strokeWidth="1.5"
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                    />
                    <path
                      d="M10.6667 2.08667C11.2403 2.23354 11.7487 2.56714 12.1118 3.03488C12.4748 3.50262 12.6719 4.07789 12.6719 4.67C12.6719 5.26212 12.4748 5.83739 12.1118 6.30513C11.7487 6.77287 11.2403 7.10647 10.6667 7.25334M14 14V12.6667C13.9966 12.0781 13.7986 11.5072 13.4368 11.0429C13.0751 10.5787 12.5699 10.2471 12 10.1M2 14V12.6667C2 11.9594 2.28095 11.2811 2.78105 10.7811C3.28115 10.281 3.95942 10 4.66667 10H7.33333C8.04058 10 8.71885 10.281 9.21895 10.7811C9.71905 11.2811 10 11.9594 10 12.6667V14H2Z"
                      stroke="#96A09B"
                      strokeWidth="1.5"
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                    />
                  </svg>
                  {item.candidates}
                </span>
                <span className="cv">
                  <svg
                    width="16"
                    height="16"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                    fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M9.33334 2V4.66667C9.33334 4.84348 9.40358 5.01305 9.52861 5.13807C9.65363 5.2631 9.8232 5.33333 10 5.33333H12.6667"
                      stroke="#96A09B"
                      strokeWidth="1.5"
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                    />
                    <path
                      d="M6.00001 8.66667H10M11.3333 14H4.66668C4.31305 14 3.97392 13.8595 3.72387 13.6095C3.47382 13.3594 3.33334 13.0203 3.33334 12.6667V3.33333C3.33334 2.97971 3.47382 2.64057 3.72387 2.39052C3.97392 2.14048 4.31305 2 4.66668 2H9.33334L12.6667 5.33333V12.6667C12.6667 13.0203 12.5262 13.3594 12.2762 13.6095C12.0261 13.8595 11.687 14 11.3333 14ZM6.00001 11.3333H10H6.00001Z"
                      stroke="#96A09B"
                      strokeWidth="1.5"
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                    />
                  </svg>
                  {item.cv}
                </span>
              </div>

              {/* user info */}
              <div className="hr-info">
                <img src={item.image} alt="" />
                <div>
                  <span id="rekruter">Рекруитер</span>
                  <span id="hr_name">{item.hr_name}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      // </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="cards">{cardItems}</div>;
};

export default Cards;
```

[image: Result of code]

Comment: Please provide all code in a code snippet of stackoverflow, or on a live editor like codesandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rain-34v38w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think you are missing the style, I think it's the core thing, Don't you want to make the all todo list in the same length as the second screenshot?

Comment: no second screenshot is incorrect, I want do what on 1st screenshot

Comment: Ok please add the style, I think the issue with the style, I think the container has a display: flex, with stretch the children.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rain-34v38w?file=/src/styles.css It is link to css. Can you halp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246033/discussion-between-asrorbek-and-mina).

Comment: I just provide the answer with the code, please check.

Comment: Did you leave the code in the sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I provided the answer and the code below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72805214/11887902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `align-items: flex-start` to the `.cards` element who is the parent of the cards, which will prevent stretching of the cards height.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cookies-zv71c7

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: '100%'` property for the card parent element style, in this case, the div with the class name `.cards` like so:

```
<div className="cards" style={{ height: '100%' }}>{cardItems}</div>
```

that might work.

Comment: I must do my page what on 1st screenshot. Not 2nd

Comment: That's what this code sample should do. make the page what is on the 1st figma screenshot.

Comment: yes but didn't work

Comment: can you provide this codebase with the entire css? this codebase: codesandbox.io/s/happy-rain-34v38w?file=/src/App.js that you provided early the css file is empty

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rain-34v38w?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: adding `align-items: flex-start;` to the `.cards` element will do it